# VueJS Интерполяция в строке, получаемой из стэйта

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

В стэйте (vuex) есть объект с переводом строк:

```
langFile: {
   user: 'Пользователь',
   level: 'Уровень ${level}'
}
```

В компоненте в computed функции получаю его геттером:

this.getLangFile.level

Как заставить, чтобы переменная подставлялась в получаемую строку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Общий ответ

Vuex это не средство для переводов. Используйте [Vue I18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/).

Ответ на Ваш вопрос проще некуда - Вы используете неподходящий инструмент для неподходящей задачи.

### Ответ конерктно для Вашего случая

Храните только неизменяему часть строки `level: 'Уровень '`, конкотенируйте в компоненте.

Comment: Согласен, это временный вариант. Будет приходить ответ в json со всем переводом на один язык. А хранить не могу только неизменяемую часть строки, потому что в переводе может разный порядок неизменяемой и изменяемой части в разных языках. Вообще временно подошел вариант
level: (lvl) => `Уровень ${lvl}`. Этот ответ куда-то пропал. А вообще посмотрел Vue I18n, хорошая штука, учту на будущее. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Я полностью согласен с @Vasiliy Rusin, но вот ответ велосипедиста, так, на всякий пожарный.

В i18next есть прекрасная функция `$t(key, options)`, которая первым аргументом принимает ключ лексемы, а вторым передаёт дополнительные опции: контекст, число, прочие переменные.

Так вот, вам нужно сделать подобие функции `$t('Уровень ${level}', { level: 1 })`, которая примет объект со свойством level. Дальше строку придётся парсить:

- искать первое вхождение "${"
- искать после "}"
- извлекать часть строки между ${ }
- извлечённую часть использовать как имя свойства объекта и извлекать параметр.
- полученное значение подставлять в результирующую строку.

Но если париться Вам не охота - ответ Василия Русина то, что нужно!

Comment: Это уже даже не велосипед, это мотоцикл с педальками))

Comment: И не говорите))